# How to set the background-color of a SAPUI5 Table Column dynamically?

Tags: sapui5, background-color

Assume a table with a date header (days 1 till 31) of a given year and month.
The content of the table depends on the selected year and month of course.
Now, for example, assume to set the `background-color` of all "weekend" columns to "gray".

With the following code (example from http://scn.sap.com/thread/3360580) we have some problems:

1. we can only set the background of available data (assume a table with
   10 default rows but only 2 entries; so we can only set the background of the first two entries)
2. we "misuse" the tooltip property (or any other) to handle the background color
3. removing of class value seems not working this way, if we change year/month of the bound table data we should change the color accordingly

   ```
   oTemplate.bindProperty("tooltip", bindPath, function(sValue) {          
   var classToSet = "";
   switch (sValue) {
       case "A": classToSet = "cssClassX"; break;
       case "B": classToSet = "cssClassY"; break;
       default: break;
    }
    cellId = this.getId();   
    $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().removeClass("cssClassX", "cssClassY");
    $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().addClass(classToSet);
   }
   ```

More or less the question is:

**Is there a way to bound the `background-color` of a full table column on some data?**

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the `sap.me.OverlapCalender` be a better choice instead of using a table? Gives you way more freedom, especially when combined with the `sap.me.CalendarLegend` control

See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/me/OverlapCalendar.html for a working example